"is not" with list having value above 256 in python
Why is the output of this Python code so unexpected?
for ind, elem in enumerate(range(260)):
    if ind is not elem:
        print(ind , elem)

I was expecting no output but the output is-
257 257
258 258
259 259

Whereas this code gives no output, as expected-
for ind, elem in enumerate(range(260)):
    if ind != elem:
        print(ind , elem)


is is an incorrect operation to compare numbers.
As an incorrect opeation, its results will be inpredictable.
For numbers from 0 to 255, there is a known cPython optimization - which is an implementation detail, which makes each of these numbers a "singleton": any new ocurrence of such a number will reuse the same instance.
But that is an implementation detail not to be relied on.
Just use == and != to compare numbers.

One of the benefits of numbers being immutable is that you'll never care if a number is a singleton or not.

half yes.
You have to assume they are not -
For coincidence, I was just debugging an old codebase today, and it took me a couple hours to realise what was wrong is exactly it was comparing some numbers with is, (pygame constants, and a python 2 era project)

Well maybe "never" was too strong a word, but using is generally means you're doing something wrong in the first place.  The only time it's justified is when you know the thing you're comparing against is a singleton, like None.
